# MongoDB how to sort by multiple fields like this?

Tags: database, mongodb

[image]

Sorry for my English.
I want to sort like this, `'initial'` status sort first，then sort by `'create_time'`. Is this possible? I guess the `'aggregate'` may be helpful, but I don't know how it can be used in this condition.

Comment: MongoDB explains how to do this in the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort

Comment: what is the order of the status?

Comment: Please provide an example document, along with an example sorted result.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow.There is a link above shows my example.I want to get the 'initial' status first, then sort by the 'create_time' field.

Comment: @Saravana I want to get the 'initial' status document first, then other documents sort by 'create_time' field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4 for custom sort.

Use [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) to locate the position of "initial",  0 when the status is found else for -1 for all other documents and [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to keep the output index in the extra field in the document followed by [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) sort on fields.

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields-from-output-documents) with exclusion to drop the sort field to get expected output.

When you sort all the initial status document shows at top followed by sort on create_time.

```js
    db.col.aggregate([
        {
            "$addFields":{ 
                "statusValue":{
                    "$indexOfArray":[
                        ["initial"], "$status"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$sort":{
                "statusValue":-1, "create_time":-1
            }
        },
        {
            "$project":{
                "statusValue":0
            }
        }
    ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Veeram's answer, you can use the standard MongoDB `sort()` method (as per Ian Mercer's comment) as well as aggregation. For example:

```
> db.test.find()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a6eb96a2937803b14255182"),
  "status": "enabled",
  "create_time": "2018-01-16"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a6eb9722937803b14255183"),
  "status": "enabled",
  "create_time": "2018-01-10"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a6eb97b2937803b14255184"),
  "status": "disabled",
  "create_time": "2018-01-15"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a6eb9892937803b14255185"),
  "status": "initial",
  "create_time": "2018-01-08"
}
```

Sorting by `status` then by `create_time`:

```
> db.test.find().sort({status:1, create_time:1})
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a6eb97b2937803b14255184"),
  "status": "disabled",
  "create_time": "2018-01-15"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a6eb9722937803b14255183"),
  "status": "enabled",
  "create_time": "2018-01-10"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a6eb96a2937803b14255182"),
  "status": "enabled",
  "create_time": "2018-01-16"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a6eb9892937803b14255185"),
  "status": "initial",
  "create_time": "2018-01-08"
}
```

Note that the sorting order on the example above are using string sort, so `disabled` will come before `enabled` as it is sorting in alphabetical order. Ditto with the `create_time` sorting order, which is based on string comparison sort.

For richer options with regards to sorting `create_time`, you need to convert the field into an `ISODate()` object. See [Date()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/) and [Data Types in the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/)

One advantage of using cursor sort like this is index use. Properly indexed, the query could be fast without the need to be sorted in memory, since MongoDB uses the index to perform the sort. See [Create Indexes to Support Your Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/) and [Use Indexes to Sort Query Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/).

If any of these concepts are new to you, I would suggest you peruse the [MongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com/) for free courses about MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I think MongoDB is easy to get started but difficult to master, There is a long way in front of me, haha.I will learn more in what you refered above, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

aggregation can be used for advanced custom sort but in this scenario, you can use Sort() method. 
so let me just give you a small walk through over sort method in Mongo

"sort() method is used To sort documents in MongoDB, you need to use sort() method. The method accepts a document containing a list of fields along with their sorting order. To specify sorting order 1 and -1 are used. 1 is used for ascending order while -1 is used for descending order."

so in your case use sort() method:

Sorting by status than by create_time:

```
db.test.find().sort({status:-1, create_time:1})
```